# Trouble with raspberry pi and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a project in raspberry pi and I am using python. However I have a problem with the OpenCV when I am trying to run this code:

```
`import numpy as np
 import cv2

 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

I get this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 8000

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:8000:  error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor"
```

I have Python 3.4.2,OpenCV 3.1.0 and Numpy 1.8.2.

Comment: `frame` appears to be already grascale. So you can avoid the `cvtColor` line, and just do `gray = frame`

Comment: i have tried this code even without the "gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)" command but i get pretty much the same error with the difference that in the end says "in function imshow" instead of cvtColor

Comment: Can you provide a single sample frame? What happens if  you save a sample frame to a file, read it from file again and proceed as above (ie which step does not work?). Are you sure that video capture works?

Comment: Then you probably don't load the `frame` correctly in the first place. Check if `ret==True`, or the `frame` is `None`. Or even  that `cap.isOpened()`

Comment: i just tried  "if not cap.isOpened(): print("cant open camera")" and when i run it i get this message and after this again the same error.so i guess it has to do with the camera the frame the camera driver i dont know.any ideas???

Comment: i tried the command "raspistill -o image.jpg" in the terminal and i got the image so the camera works.

Comment: anyone with the same problem???any ideas???

Answer (score 2):

So I found an answer. All I had to do was run this code on my raspberry pi:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Yes you must ensure you load up the Video for Linux drivers